# template function overload with const

Tags: c++, templates

Here is a bit of code:

```
template<class T>
inline void bar(T& t) {
   foo(t); // intention is that foo() is found by ADL
}

struct Wig {
   int i;
};

void foo(int){ }

// some convenience overload
inline void bar(const Wig& w) { foo(w.i);  }

// The bit that if uncommented, "fixes" the problem
//inline void bar(Wig& w) {   foo(w.i); }

int main()
{
   Wig w;
   bar(w);
   return 0;
}
```

Clang 3.5 and Gcc 4.7, spit out the following error:

```
template-function-overload.cpp:12:4: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
   foo(t);
   ^~~
template-function-overload.cpp:29:4: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'bar<Wig>' requested here
   bar(w);
   ^
template-function-overload.cpp:19:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from
      'Wig' to 'int' for 1st argument
void foo(int){ }
     ^
```

So it doesn't look like a compiler issue.

Also, commenting out the non-const overload fixes the error.

Why is this code incorrect, and why a non-const overload required?

Comment: You need to declare `foo` before you call it.

Comment: That is not correct for a template context, and it not how ADL works. And also please note, with the non-const overload the code is legit.

Comment: Whatever. You clearly understand this very well.

Comment: Not clearly, not very well..  I simply fell into this pitfall and trying to understand what is going on..   If you think about it, it is quite an easy to miss C++-esque detail.  Consider a real code where the general template (`bar`) is hidden deep down in some include hierarchy, and you are trying to implement a simple facade class (`Wig`) that contains bunch of implementation data (int) and want to present a "friendly" version of `bar`.  No more templates, and everything is `const`.  Yet, the compilers croak.

Comment: If you were to provide `void foo(const struct Wig&) {}` before the function template `bar` the code would compile. That is what I meant in my first comment and it is correct.

Comment: There is no `foo(.. Wig&)` at all.  Not before, not after.  There is `bar(Wig&)` which forwards an internal `int` to an existing `foo`.  Sorry, the symbol names are not very clear.

Comment: I said "You need to declare foo before you call it." The reason you get a compiler error is because you're instantiating the function template and it cannot find an appropriate `foo` function to call. If you provide that function *before* the function template definition, the code compiles. It is very simple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the `bar(w)` call, overload resolution compares

```
void bar<Wig>(Wig&); // instantiated from the template
void bar(const Wig &);
```

Binding to a reference to a less cv-qualified type is better ([over.ics.rank], bullet 3.2.6), so the first signature is chosen. That template attempts to call `foo` on a `Wig`, but there's no such thing, hence the error.

With the extra non-const overload, we are now comparing (plus the `const Wig &` that's worse than either):

```
void bar<Wig>(Wig&); // instantiated from the template
void bar(Wig&);
```

The parameter types are identical, so the two are indistinguishable by ranking conversion sequences, and instead the tiebreaker in [over.match.best] bullet 1.6 selects the non-template over the function template specialization.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for the pointers to the standard and explaining how template enters into ranking.